# Replace with "?" all elements in a slice / create a string with ?, for as many elements in a slice

Tags: arrays, string, go, replace, slice

I'm doing my first assignment in Golang, hence this may be silly question.

I have a situation where I need to create a query dynamically that takes an `array` (`slice`) of parameters, thus an equal number of "`?`" pre execution.

Here it is:

```
var reportIds []int // eg [1, 2, 3, 4]

values := make([]interface{}, 0, len(reportIds))
for  key, _ := range reportIds {
  values = append(values, reportIds[key])
}

statement, _ :=
    database.Prepare("DELETE FROM reports WHERE id IN ({??my_dynamic_question_marks??})")
statement.Exec(values...)
```

It works for the values but I cannot understand whether there is a clean way of replacing a `n` number of elements in a slice with "`?`" so that I could then `join` it into a string.
I came up with this idea since it seems clean but any way of creating a string with "`?,` " for as many elements in the `slice` would work (natually the last one without comma).

I could do that implementing a counter in the `for` loop of course and build the string dynamically but I was wondering whether there a cleaner or more "official" way of doing it

Comment: Just do a concat in the same loop, and at the end, outside of the loop, slice off the last byte (comma). https://play.golang.org/p/78zg9xTmVSa

Comment: You could also do [this](https://play.golang.org/p/75ryEl-s5Ys) if you like, but that's doing more work underneath than the manual loop in the previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a slice of `"?"` strings, and then join them together with `strings.Join`, which accepts a slice of strings and a delimiter:

```
var reportIds []int // eg [1, 2, 3, 4]

values := make([]interface{}, len(reportIds))
placeHolders := make([]string, len(reportIds))

for idx, reportID := range reportIds {
  values[idx] = reportID
  placeHolders[idx] = "?"
}

strings.Join(placeHolders, ",") // => "?,?,?,?"
```